# How to determine the value of $\,\,A^{\frac {1}{100}}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem which one of my friends gave me:

> Let $A=10^{10^{10}}$. Then I have to determine the value of $A^{\frac {1}{100}}.$
>
> The options are :
>
> 1. $10^{8^{10}}$
> 2. $10^{10^{8}}$
> 3. $10^{10}$
> 4. $10^{10^{10}-2}$

Can someone give explanation with some details? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\displaystyle a^{m^n}=a^{(m^n)}$
$$A=10^{10^{10}}=(10)^{10^{10}}$$

$$\implies A^{\frac1{100}}=\left((10)^{10^{10}}\right)^{\frac1{100}} =10^{\frac{10^{10}}{100}}=10^{10^{10}\cdot10^{-2}}=10^{(10^{10-2})}$$ as $\displaystyle a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$ and $\displaystyle a^{-m}=\frac1{a^m}$

Comment: @learner, $$(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$$ is a candidate confusion for $$a^{m^n}=a^{(m^n)}$$. Clearly, these two are in general not equal

Comment: thanks a lot sir for the nice explanation.....